# How to add wordpress pagination to an existing array of pages?

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, pagination

I have searched for some time on this issue and come up blank, so hopefully someone can help me.

I am putting together an Events page within a custom theme that is divided into two sections: "upcoming events", and "past events" (archive). I have successfully managed to pull in all of the posts of the category, "events" and then divide them into two arrays based on the "event-date" post_meta entered for each, but I need one of these arrays ($past_events) to be paginated.

I am comfortable using pagination in general, and have no problem using offsets and whatnot, but I don't know how to add the "paged" attribute to an array that does not already have it set.

Is this possible? Or will I have to run a new query, compare the results to those in $past_events, and do something crazy with the offset value??

Thanks in advance.

Mike

Comment: Why do you have to split the query into two arrays? Wouldn't running two separate queries be easier? Standard paginate_links() could be used quite easily from there.

Comment: @henrywright Well that's what I thought originally, but I wasn't sure how to run a WP_Query that reads a specific post_meta (which lists a date in the format dd/mm/yyyy, which I then compare to today's date) _and_ excludes those later than "today", without messing up the pagination. I figured that if I got the posts I wanted from the original array, there must be some way to achieve what I wanted, but then I hit this roadblock. Can you offer me any advice?

Comment: See this link for more info on how you can build your query using the new date parameters WordPress introduced in 3.7. You might have to use some custom field parameters in your query too (see the section immediately below the data parameter section) http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Date_Parameters

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into that further. I'm pretty sure the answer's in there somewhere!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for the massively long period of time since I last commented. I got caught up having to work on another project and then my laptop died on me.

Anyway, I found a solution using henrywright's advice.

Starting from the suggestion to use two separate queries, and using information about WP_Query and meta_query found at the link given in the comments above, I produced the following code:

```
    <?php 
    $today = date('Y/m/d');
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'category_name' => 'Event',
        'meta_key' => 'event-date',
        'orderby' => 'meta_value',
        'paged' => $paged,
        'posts_per_page' => 3,
        'meta_query' => array(
                array(
                    'key' => 'event-date',
                    'value' => $today,
                    'compare' => '<'
                )
        )
    );
    $event_archive = new WP_Query($args); ?>
```

I will briefly explain this for any noobs like me that might come across this and not understand.

$today stores today's date in the format yyyy/mm/dd

The $args array gets all posts from the category, "Event",and orders them by the meta_value (in this case it is the date of the event, which has been entered as the value of a custom field - "event-date" - and MUST be in the same format as $today for the query to work)

The meta_query looks at the values of the "event-date" custom field in all relevant posts, and compares the contents to the value $today and returns all those that are "less than" $today, i.e. *in the past*

The returned posts are paginated at 3 per page. The code used to add numbered pagination to this was based on that found [here](http://www.catswhocode.com/blog/snippets/wordpress-simple-numbered-pagination-without-a-plugin).

Okay, so not necessarily a "brief" explanation, but this is the level of detail I like in an explanation, so I think it's reasonable to assume that this is true for others as well.

Thanks to henrywright for pointing me in the wright (ha) direction.